# How to derive the distribution of $X_{(n)}$ when $X_{1}, \dots X_{n}$ are i.i.d. $Uni[0, \theta]$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X_{(1)}, \dots X_{(n)}$ be i.i.d. in the $Uni[0, \theta]$ distribution. I want to show that the estimator $X_{(n)}$ is unbiased when estimating $\theta$ in the $Uni[0, \theta]$ distribution. To do this, I want to compute $\mathbb{E}(X_{(n)})$, but I am having trouble deriving the distribution for $X_{(n)}$. In an example in my book, it is stated that $\mathbb{E}_{\theta}(X_{(n)}) = \int_{0}^{\theta} xnx^{n-1}\frac{1}{\theta^n}dx$. Here are some of my thoughts when trying to figure this out: \

- We are working with ordered statistics, so X_{(n)} is the biggest value that's been found/measured. We know that $X_{1}, \dots, X_{n}$ are uniformly distributed, so $X_{(n)}$ is a sample from this uniform distribution as well. But we do not know the bounds, so we are stuck with the same problem.
- I have tried to formalize this problem by writing $X_{(n)} := max \{X_{i}| i \in [1,\dots,n] \}$ and then stating that $F(x) = \mathbb{P}(X \leq x) = \int_{-\infty}^{x}f(s)ds = \int_{0}^{x}f(s)ds$. I understand that $\theta$ is the maximum value that $X_{(n)}$ can have, but I am getting stuck when I need to find $f(x)$. Can I state that $\mathbb{P}(X \leq x) = \mathbb{P}(X_{(n)} \leq x)$? Or even $\mathbb{P}(X \leq x) = \mathbb{P}(X_{(n)} \leq \theta)$?
- I find it intuitive that $f(x)$ is a rising function, since the probability of the biggest found value 'being close' to the maximum allowed value, is rising with more samples.

Can somebody help me with this derivation?

Comment: Hint: $\mathbb{P}(X_{(n)} \le x) = \mathbb{P}(X_1 \le x, \ldots, X_n \le x) = \prod_{k = 1}^n \mathbb{P}(X_k \le x)$

Comment: Thank you! That really helps. I found it.

Comment: @D13n3 it is best if you mark the question as solved :)

Comment: @ThànhNguyễn It would be a good idea to post that as an answer so the question can be marked as solved.

Comment: The tag [distribution-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/distribution-theory) is not about probability distributions. I have therefore removed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually when computing the distribution of the maximum, one argues as follows:

\begin{align}
F_{X_{(n)})}(x) &= P(\max X_i \leq x) \\
&= P(X_1 \leq x,  X_2 \leq x, \ldots X_n \leq x) \\ 
&= \prod_i P(X_i \leq x) \\
&= \frac{y^n}{\theta^n}
\end{align}
You may then use this CDF to compute the expectation of the maximum.